# Algorithm: Finding median in a sorted array with duplicates

Tags: algorithms, arrays, searching

If array is sorted we can generally find median in O(1) by returning the element at the middle. 
But what if there are duplicates?

E.g [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]

Comment: The same. And when the length is even there are various definitions: return mean of teo middle elements or the lower (upper) one to keep median as element of the set. There is no definition depending on elements in the array.

Comment: Now, if you wanted median(set(input)), rather than median(input), then things would be significantly harder. ​ ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Even with duplicates, the process of finding median is same. See  this link - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191119/how-to-find-the-median-of-three-numbers-if-one-of-them-appears-twice

Comment: How does that link help answering the question?